# WPF - Trigger em elementos dentro de um wrap panel

Tags: c#, style

Eu tenho um wrap panel que contém diversos dockpanels, e preciso que cada dockpanel altere seu background ao passar o mouse sobre ele. Acho que criar um trigger para cada elemento não seria adequado.
Meu xaml está assim:

```
<StackPanel>
    <WrapPanel>
        <DockPanel> <!-- Aqui eu tenho muitos DockPanels -->
        </DockPanel>
    </WrapPanel
</StackPanel>
```

O que consegui foi buscar todos os elementos filhos usando:

```
Children.OfType<DockPanel>().Any();
```

Mas não consigo definir qual objeto o mouse está em cima pra alterá-lo

Comment: Obteve algum resultado  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho  que  a forma mais coerente para fazer o que quer é criar um  trigger

crie um  style resource

```
<Style x:Key="MeuMauseOver" TargetType="DockPanel">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="blue"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

E defina o  style para os dockpanels

```
<StackPanel>
    <WrapPanel>
        <DockPanel Style="{StaticResource MeuMauseOver}">
        </DockPanel>
    </WrapPanel
</StackPanel>
```

Caso esteja criando  os dockpanels pelo codigo pode pegar o stylo pelo 
Resource.

```
Style MeuMauseOver = this.FindResource("MeuMauseOver") as Style;
```

A onde this precisa ser um elemento  Window. no  caso seu MainWindow.

Mas seguindo  seu contexto de pegar todos os elementos que o mouseover esta igual  a true você pode fazer algo similar a isso

```
Children.OfType<DockPanel>().Where(x => x.IsMouseOver == true);
```